# perl + mysql Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

It seems a common problem and I've searched a lot but haven't successfully find any solution to my situation. Tried mysql_auto_reconnect and connect_cached but did not help. This is basically the code I have here.
The mysql server will close the connection after 30 seconds idleness. The mysql_auto_reconnect only works when I first $dbh->disconnect from the server(commented in the code). The connect_cached method works here but I still got "lost connection" message using connect_cached method in a while loop.

```
  my $dbh = DBI->connect_cached($mysql_data_source, $mysql_username, $mysql_passwd, {'RaiseError' => 1});
  $dbh->{AutoInactiveDestroy} = 1;
  $dbh->{mysql_auto_reconnect} = 1;
  print strftime('%F %T', localtime());
  print "\n";
  #$dbh->disconnect();
  sleep 30; 
  $dbh = DBI->connect_cached($mysql_data_source, $mysql_username, $mysql_passwd, {'RaiseError' => 1});
  print strftime('%F %T', localtime());
  my $sql = "some sql";
  my $hashref = $dbh->selectall_hashref($sql, "id");
  my $info_hashref = $dbh->{mysql_dbd_stats};
  print Dumper($info_hashref);
  print Dumper($hashref);
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try manipulating the timeout, perhaps by adding this to your connect: mysql_connect_timeout=60

Of course if the query takes that long, it might be advisable to review the sql.

Comment: mysql_auto_reconnect and $dbh->ping() works. DBD::Safe is a better choice.